# Node.js http - send GET data to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

How can I send data with GET method using https/http module? With POST everything works.

**First code** (**GET**):

```
var querystring = require('querystring'),
    protocol = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'httpbin.org',
  path: 'get',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {},
  port: 443
};

var data = querystring.stringify({
  limit: 3
});

Object.assign(options.headers, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
});

var req = protocol.request(options, response => {
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  var end = '';
  response.on('data', data => end += data);
  response.on('end', () => console.log(end));
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Response:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "7",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  },
  "origin": "31.0.120.218",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

**Second code** (**POST**, I only replaced *options* object):

```
var options = {
  host: 'httpbin.org',
  path: 'post',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {},
  port: 443
};
```

Response:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "limit": "3"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "7",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "31.0.120.218",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

I will be very grateful for some help, now I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Not really a node.js issue. For GET, you do not post data in the body because it's not part of the http specification. The GET method is usually used for querying things. You send query parameters via the URL. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in a get, the query is appended to the path, as @Quy points out, get requests don't have a body. Without an understanding of how the server is set up, I would look at doing it like so:

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
  limit: 3
});

var options = {
  host: 'httpbin.org',
  path: 'get?' + data,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {},
  port: 443
};
```